# Django CharField TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'empty_value'

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

The Django suggest that I can set the `empty_value` for a CharField: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.empty_value

I'm trying to change my field from:

```
my_field = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
```

to:

```
my_field = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True, empty_value=None)
```

I'm getting this error when I try to create the migration:

> File "/Virtualenv/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py", line 1039, in **init**
>       super().**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>   TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'empty_value'

The reason is because I want to set a `unique_together` on the model that includes `my_field` and other fields, with the following behavior:

- If `my_field` is NULL, I want the `unique_together` clause to always allow other combinations because [NULL != NULL in SQL](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28545).
- If `my_field` is not NULL, I want the `unique_together` clause to check for uniqueness against the other field(s).

I do not want validation that is not database validation like a `clean` or `validate_my_field` method or similar.

Comment: That link using for Django Form fields, not model fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You trying to use `forms.CharField` as `models.CharField` that doesn't have `empty_value`. For models you need to use [`default` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#default).

In which file this code?

If in `models.py` (you define model), then use `default` instead of `empty_value`.

If in `forms.py` (you define form), then import `django.forms`, not `django.db.models` and then you can use:

```py
my_field = forms.CharField(max_length=80, required=False, empty_value=None)
```